# index.html:121 Uncaught ReferenceError: (function) is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick(

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

We are trying to make a memory game but we are getting an error on our functions: startGame, imgClick, etc.
The cards are supposed to shuffle at random when we press the start button.

We are getting images from firebase storage and use an array of strings to shuffel their position in our game.

when we try to start the game we get an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: startGame is not defined at
> HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:121:64)

Javascript (in the <head>)

```
  <script type="module">
  import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.2/firebase-app.js";
  import { getStorage, ref, getDownloadURL } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.2/firebase-storage.js";

  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "*****************",
    authDomain: "filetirgul.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://filetirgul-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "filetirgul",
    storageBucket: "filetirgul.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "53849089655",
    appId: "1:53849089655:web:**************"
  };
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  var started = false;

  var backOfCards = "gs://filetirgul.appspot.com/think.jpg";

  var images = ["monkey.jpg","monkey2.jpg","face.jpg","face2.jpg","office.jpg","office2.jpg","cat.jpg","cat2.jpg","drunk.jpg","drunk2.jpg","donky.jpg","donky2.jpg","hally.jpg","hally2.jpg","potato.jpg","potato2.jpg"]


  var backOfCards = "gs://filetirgul.appspot.com/think.jpg";

  var images = ["monkey.jpg","monkey2.jpg","face.jpg","face2.jpg","office.jpg","office2.jpg","cat.jpg","cat2.jpg","drunk.jpg","drunk2.jpg","donky.jpg","donky2.jpg","hally.jpg","hally2.jpg","potato.jpg","potato2.jpg"]

  document.getElementById('img1').addEventListener('click', imgClick(1));
  document.getElementById('img2').addEventListener('click', imgClick(2));
  document.getElementById('img3').addEventListener('click', imgClick(3));
  document.getElementById('img4').addEventListener('click', imgClick(4));
  document.getElementById('img5').addEventListener('click', imgClick(5));
  document.getElementById('img6').addEventListener('click', imgClick(6));
  document.getElementById('img7').addEventListener('click', imgClick(7));
  document.getElementById('img8').addEventListener('click', imgClick(8));
  document.getElementById('img9').addEventListener('click', imgClick(9));
  document.getElementById('img10').addEventListener('click', imgClick(10));
  document.getElementById('img11').addEventListener('click', imgClick(11));
  document.getElementById('img12').addEventListener('click', imgClick(12));
  document.getElementById('img13').addEventListener('click', imgClick(13));
  document.getElementById('img14').addEventListener('click', imgClick(14));
  document.getElementById('img15').addEventListener('click', imgClick(15));
  document.getElementById('img16').addEventListener('click', imgClick(16));

  function imgClick(index) {
    if (started) {
      const storage = getStorage(app);
      getDownloadURL(ref(storage, images[index-1]))
      .then((url) => {
      // Or inserted into an <img> element
      var img = document.getElementById('img' + index);
      img.setAttribute('src', url);
      });
    }
  }

  function startGame() {
      shuffle();
      started = true;
      for (let i = 0 ; i < images.length ; i++) {
        const storage = getStorage(app);
        getDownloadURL(ref(storage,
          [index-1]))
        .then((url) => {
          // Or inserted into an <img> element
          var img = document.getElementById('img' + index);
          img.setAttribute('src', url);
      });
    }
  }


  function shuffle() {
    for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      let currentIndex = i;
      let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length);
      let tempImg = images[currentIndex];

      images[currentIndex] = images[randomIndex];
      images[randomIndex] = tempImg;
    }
  }

  </script>
```

HTML

```
</head>
  <body>
    <div class="body">
      <div class="gameArea">
        <div id="c1"><img id="img1" src="img/think.jpg" alt="image" height="200" width="200"><img></div>
        <div id="c2"><img id="img2" src="img/think.jpg" alt="image" height="200" width="200"></div>
        <div id="c3"><img id="img3" src="img/think.jpg" alt="image" height="200" width="200"></div>
        <div id="c4"><img id="img4" src="img/think.jpg" alt="image" height="200" width="200"></div>
        <div id="c5"><img id="img5" src="img/think.jpg" alt="image" height="200" width="200"></div>
        <div id="c6"><img id="img6" src="img/think.jpg" alt="image" height="200" width="200"></div>
        <div id="c7"><img id="img7" src="img/think.jpg" alt="image" height="200" width="200"></div>
        <div id="c8"><img id="img8" src="img/think.jpg" alt="image" height="200" width="200"></div>
        <div id="c9"><img id="img9" src="img/think.jpg" alt="image" height="200" width="200"></div>
        <div id="ca"><img id="img10" src="img/think.jpg" alt="image" height="200" width="200"></div>
        <div id="cb"><img id="img11" src="img/think.jpg" alt="image" height="200" width="200"></div>
        <div id="cc"><img id="img12" src="img/think.jpg" alt="image" height="200" width="200"></div>
        <div id="cd"><img id="img13" src="img/think.jpg" alt="image" height="200" width="200"></div>
        <div id="ce"><img id="img14" src="img/think.jpg" alt="image" height="200" width="200"></div>
        <div id="cf"><img id="img15" src="img/think.jpg" alt="image" height="200" width="200"></div>
        <div id="cg"><img id="img16" src="img/think.jpg" alt="image" height="200" width="200"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="toggleGame">
        <button class="start" id="start" onclick="startGame()">Start</button>
      </div>
      <div class="highscore">
        Highscore:
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are using script type module , do you use some kind of compiler like `browserify` ...
Don't post your API key it is a secret!

Answer (score 1):

Add this

```js
document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', startGame);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the event listener for the start button.

Pure js:

```
document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', startGame);
```

Comment: Previous answer seems the same.

Comment: Seems like you just add the explanation to @tszhong0411's answer. It will be much better to edit his answer instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Yes, i guess we answered in minutes diff 